# What should I do when I want Y and folks make assumptions about X?

Tags: discussion, asking-questions, xy-problem

Contributors often respond to questions with references to the XY problem - [What is the XY problem?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem)  ("What's the X that you need **Y** for?"). That's fine. It's also fine when they add something about it in their answer to Y.

But sometimes I might actually want *Y*, rather than some other solution to X!

Why? Maybe there is some fixed requirement (whether justified or not). Or some drawback of the usual way of achieving X. Or maybe some other reason you don't know of. And maybe I don't even want to tell you what X is, because that will lead to a barrage of answers I'm not interested in, and maybe even to my question being closed as a duplicate of 'another' question about X.

So what should my response be to this?

Comment: Editing and reopening because this is a fairly common question and I like Servy's answer.

Answer (score 18):

Then *explain that in the question*.  If you explain what you need to do *with any additional constraints that you have been given*, then people can attempt to provide solutions to your problem that fit within your constraints.  If there are similar questions without the same constraints, then they aren't duplicates (even if related) so long as the constraints inhibit the use of the answers (and they are still duplicates if the constraints *don't* inhibit the use of the other answers).

Comment: If I ask how to achieve Y - I don't _have_ to explain why I don't want to achieve X using Z. My question is about Y. Period.

Comment: @ispiro And your refusal to provide the requested information has resulted in your question not getting an answer.  You don't *have* to do anything, but you also don't have to get an answer.  Including information relevant to your problem increases the odds of you getting a quality answer; if you don't need/want one, then that's your decision.

Comment: What question are you talking about? The one that was recently downvoted by the meta-effect? I wasn't actually referring to any specific question. But I guess that's the risk of asking on meta... Oh well...

Comment: @ispiro The point remains.  Including this information improves the question, and thus improves the odds of getting a good answer.  You *might* be able to get an answer without including it, but you're better off including it, and users are correct to request that you improve your question in this manor.

Comment: @ispiro Trouble-shooting normally has these steps: 1. Recognize there's a problem 2. Identify the problem 3. Solve the problem. If it seems obvious you failed on step one or two (which is equivalent to not demonstrating you succeeded and can explain it properly), doing step 3 is a) not possible or b) not useful or even c) actively harmful.